# Linux Extract login history of all users

Tags: bash

I currently have this bash script that is able to extract login history of all users in a certain time period, but I am trying to do so for all history not just between a certain time period.

Would it be more beneficial to grab this data from /var/log/secure?

Can anyone help steer me in the right direction?

```
last | while read line
do
    date=`date -d "$(echo $line | awk '{ print $5" "$6" "$7 }')" +%s`
    [[ $date -ge `date -d "Aug 25 00:00" +%s` && $date -le `date -d "Aug 28 00:00" +%s` ]] && echo $line
done
```

Answer (score 0):

For the whole history just run `last`

Or

from `last --help`

```
-s --since
-t --until
```

Ex:

```
last -s 2019-01-30
```

For older login history you can try

```
last -s YYYY-MM-DD -f /var/log/wtmp.1 #
```

Comment: Vitorino just for clarification, if I have just last in my bash script it’ll do all users login history?

Comment: yes. From last man "last searches back through the /var/log/wtmp file (or the file designated by the -f option) and displays a list of all users logged in (and out) since that file was created."

Comment: Vitorino Thanks for the clarification, is there anything special that I need to keep in mind if I’m writing the output of this to a file in my home directory?

Comment: Vitorino We were asked to have the output written to a file we created in our home directory then use cron to schedule it weekly